# Transaction Amount delimiter must be dot in SQL

Tags: sql, delimiter

My SQL column in Hadoop contains amounts of transactions with delimiter dot `.`.
I need to check if there are any errors and other delimiters are used (e.g. comma).
Expected results shows that all transactions use dot or are round and do not have delimiters.

Example:

```
22.3
-14.40
5
10.30
15.25
etc.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to check correctness of the column by using SQL code?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.